# Linear Algebra - Image & kernel of a linear map and the dimension of vector subspaces, link between rank & nullity and image & kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra

Really vague title, sorry I can't think of a way to describe it succinctly. I have a problem and a solution to the problem but I don't understand the last line of the explanation. Would appreciate it greatly if someone could explain it in more detail.

[image: The Question]

[image: The Solution]

I am struggling to understand the logic behind line "By (i), the spaces im(T) and ker(T) have the same dimension." I think is there some link between the image & kernel and the rank & nullity that I don't know?

Comment: *Nullity* is dimension of kernel. *Rank* is dimension of image. Rank plus nullity equals dimension of domain (equals number of columns of matrix). Does that settle it for you, or do you need something more?

Comment: In this particular case, the rank can't be zero (and the nullity can't be two) since $A$ is not the zero matrix. The rank can't be two (and the nulltiy can't be zero) since $A^2$ is the zero matrix. So the rank must be one, and the nullity must be one, so in particular the rank and nullity are equal, so the dimensions of the image and the kernel are equal.

Comment: Thank-you Gerry that makes a lot of sense actually, if you want to post that as an answer not a comment I will gladly mark it as the answer

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Nullity* is dimension of kernel. *Rank* is dimension of image. Rank plus nullity equals dimension of domain (equals number of columns of matrix).

In this particular case, the rank can't be zero (and the nullity can't be two) since $A$
 is not the zero matrix. The rank can't be two (and the nullity can't be zero) since $A^2$
 is the zero matrix. So the rank must be one, and the nullity must be one, so in particular the rank and nullity are equal, so the dimensions of the image and the kernel are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the dimension theorem. If $T: W \to V$ is a linear transformation then $\dim W = \dim \ker (T) + \dim \operatorname {rank} (T) $.